# Maven - POM: How to make the jetty port changeable so that it can be retrieved later?

Tags: maven-2, jetty, pom.xml

I'm working on an integration test suite and I've got a question for you.

My parent pom defines the use of the jetty plugin with the goal: run-war. I need to make the port that jetty listens on changeable via the command-line. This can be achieved by passing -Djetty.port=8099 for example.

In the child project, I need to use this port number to configure the endpoint for some SOAP tests that I'll need to run on the service hosted by jetty.

If I use ${jetty.port} in my child pom in the end-point configuration this works fine IF and only IF I explicitly pass -Djetty.port when invoking maven.

In my child pom:

```
<endpoint>http://127.0.0.1:${jetty.port}/{artifactId}<endpoint>
```

I need jetty.port to be filled in with 8080 which is what jetty defaults to if -Djetty.port is not explicitly passed, and still catch any other port values if the command line argument is specified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the properties section, and add a jetty.port property with a default value:

```
<properties>
  <jetty.port>8080</jetty.port>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't too hard :-) I'll accept this post as an answer as soon as the timer runs out.

Comment: Yeah - it doesn't work for me either.  I can do -Djetty.port=8080 at the command line, but putting <jeety.port> in the pom doesn't work.

Comment: You can also do: export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djetty.port=9999" this env. variable obviates the need for command-line option.

Comment: Very useful answer, especially since the documentation is currently incorrect on this, and wrongly says that the property should be `jetty.http.port`, which no longer works.

Comment: only export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djetty.port=9999"  has worked for me so far

Answer (score 8):

config maven jetty plugin:

```
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1H.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8085</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

If you want to use a newer version of jetty plugin, use the following configuration:
From http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html:

> You could instead configure the connectors in a standard jetty xml config file and put its location into the jettyXml parameter. Note that **since jetty-9.0 it is no longer possible to configure a https connector directly in the pom.xml: you need to use jetty xml config files to do it**.
>   
>   Something like:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.5.v20130815</version>
        <configuration>
            <jettyXml>src/main/resources/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
            <webApp>
                <contextPath>/yourCtxPath</contextPath>
            </webApp>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

would do the trick, with 
jetty.xml file content:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call id="httpsConnector" name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
          <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
          <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8085" /></Set>
          <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

</Configure>
```

---

See the log after 'mvn jetty:run', at the end should show something like: 
2013-09-05 09:49:05.047:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@a6e9cb4{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:**8085**}

You will need to use maven 3 and java 7 for this version of plugin.